# How can I select multiple views in design section in xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

How can I select multiple views in design section in xml? For example, I selected only one `CheckBox` on the screenshot just by clicking on it:

[image]

Now I want to select two another `CheckBoxes`. I try pressing `Ctrl` and clicking on them, but such attempt only opens up an xml markup of the selected element for me, but selects nothing. I am stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Shift` instead of `Ctrl` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, either **Shift** or **Control** key held down with pressing **mouse click** selects multiple views in the design section of Android Studio.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts
(as of September 18, 2023)